# rest api sub resource

Tags: api, rest

I asked a similar question but perhaps it was too complicated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900550/rest-api-design-for-performing-different-actions-on-an-underlying-object?noredirect=1#comment42354797_26900550

The business rules for my system are as follows:

1. Users can create/update a job with customer and site address (address changes for each job). A new quote automatically creates a new quote with status = new (1 quote per job only)
2. Users can update the quote details - total, markup etc..
3. There are several quote statuses (new, sent, on hold, won, lost). Each status needs to be accompanied by data unique to the status e.g. 'sent' requires a sent date, 'won' and 'lost' requires a decision date. When jobs are marked as won, one or more purchase order records are required against the job, so I would like to receive an array of purchase order records along with status=won.

I am trying to use nouns and sub-resources as a best practice and not necessarily make the rest api match my database model but it is new and scary.

```
jobs (get, post)
jobs/{id} (get, put)
jobs/{id}/status (post, delete)
jobs/{id}/quote  (post, put, delete)
jobs/{id}/quote/decision (post, delete)
```

The last endpoint is where the quote status will change to won/lost etc.. The delete functionality is in case the job was accidentally marked as won/lost and needs to be returned to sent.

Can anyone offer recommendations or insights into whether this is a good way to architect the api or am I overdoing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUT always requires the whole representation of a resource, if you want to do partial update, you need PATCH.

If you already know the URI of a resource, for example `jobs/{id}/quote` then use PUT or PATCH for the creation instead of POST. POST is rather for creation of item resources in a collection and not for creation of sub-resources.

Be aware that you are defining links, e.g. `GET jobs`, `POST jobs` and so on... The responses you give for a GET should contain these links, so the client can use them. You need to add metadata to these links, for example [link relations](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) or RDF attributes from a [related vocab](http://schema.org/), etc... So the client will know what the links does. The nouns in the URIs are just for checking whether we are really talking about resources and not operations, the clients have nothing to do with the URI structure.

*I suggest you to read the [REST constraints](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) at first. After that you should read the basics of the HTTP standard. You should find a proper hypermedia format as well, for example HAL+JSON or JSONLD+Hydra if you prefer RDF. After that you can work.*